Problem in finding the determinant of a 21by21 matrix using a C++ program
I have been using a C++ program to calculate the deteminant of a nbyn
square matrix. It works well for lower orders ( I have got exact results for n=6). I need to calculate the determinant of a 21by21 matrix but the program takes infinite time to calculate the determinant.
I am writing down the code I used:
# include<iostream>
# include<fstream>
# include<cmath>
   
using namespace std;
float determinant( float matrix2[21][21], int n2)
{
    float det = 0;
    float submatrix2[21][21];
    if (n2 == 2)
        return ((matrix2[1][1] * matrix2[0][0]) - (matrix2[0][1] * matrix2[1][0]));
    else {
        for (int l = 0; l < n2; l++) {
            int subi = 0;
            for (int m = 1; m < n2; m++) {
                int  subj = 0;
                for (int p = 0; p < n2; p++) {
                    if (p == l)
                        continue;
                    submatrix2[subi][subj] = matrix2[m][p];
                    subj++;
                }
                subi++;
            }
            det = det + (pow(-1, l) * matrix2[0][l] * determinant( submatrix2, n2 - 1 ));
        }
    }
    return det;
}

int main()
{
    ifstream aa("matrix21.dat");
    float a[21][21];
    int p,q;
    for(p=0;p<21;p++)
    {
        for(q=0;q<21;q++)
        {
            aa>>a[p][q];
        }
    }
    for(p=0;p<21;p++)
    {
        for(q=0;q<21;q++)
        {
            cout<<a[p][q]<<"  ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    float det;
    det=determinant(a,21);
    cout<<"The determinant is :"<<det<<endl;
    return(0);
}

Even I tried giving a diagonal matrix in the input file, but the program fails to deliver the result.

Why not use a library, like eigen? Also try to use double i.o float you will have smaller numerical errors that can accumulate. Also the use of std::pow is not necessary here, just use 1.0/l (the pow function will not give accurate results either).
Tip make your code more generic so you can test and debug with smaller matrices first (yes if you're going to write your own code you need to debug)

Expansion in minors (your recursive method) might be (one) theoretical way of computing determinants, but it is very poor computationally, as you spawn vast numbers of sub-determinants and your recursion explodes. Unless it's particularly badly conditioned you can try reducing your matrix to row-echelon form (something akin to what you would do for gauss-elimination); the remaining determinant is just the product of diagonal elements.

@lastchance "Laplacian" determinant. I would say that it exist historically rather as a theoretical step to prove other theoremas and lemmas, not as as practical method. Plain Leibniz formula in some cases is more practical than Laplace.

det = det + (pow(-1, l)... rather big source of errors when you deal with floating point. For computers, a + b + c wound't be equal to a + c + b in FP math , if difference in values is great. Number of operations to calculate 21x21 matrix using this is around 4.4e21 operations. Which takes huge time and wouldn't yeild correct result. It's O(n!) after all.

If you try to use the expansion in minors then 21 minors will each trigger the expansion of 20 minors which will each trigger the expansion of 19 minors, ... etc. etc. Even with some judicious memoisation this would be untenable.
Instead, you can carry out the steps you would carry out with Gaussian elimination to reduce the matrix to upper-triangular form. Once you have zeros below the lead diagonal then the determinant is just the product of the diagonal elements.
Note that partial pivoting (swapping rows to put the largest possible element in the pivot position) is usually desirable for numerical stability. Every row swap changes the sign of the determinant by -1.
Note that 21x21 matrices can have rather large determinants; watch out for overflow.
Here's a c++ code and its output for a 21x21 matrix (given at the bottom). Make sure that your code knows how big a matrix it is expecting to read from file.
I checked it with Python (by cheating and using the numpy.linalg library).
c++ code
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

const double SMALL = 1.0E-30;

using matrix = vector< vector<double> >;

//======================================================================

matrix readMatrix( int N, string filename )      // It is assumed you know how big your matrix is!
{
   matrix M( N, vector<double>( N ) );
   ifstream in( filename );
   for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
   {
      for ( int j = 0; j < N; j++ ) in >> M[i][j];
   }
   return M;
}

//======================================================================

double determinant( matrix A )
{
   int n = A.size();
   double det = 1;

   // Reduce to row-echelon form by pivoting from rows i = 0, ,,,, n - 2 (n-1 not needed)
   // Better numerics by swapping rows to put largest possible element as pivot
   // The determinant changes sign when you swap rows, so keep a tally!
   // After reduction to RE form, the determinant is just the product of the diagonal elements

   for ( int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++ )
   {
      // Partial pivot: find row r below with largest element in column i
      int r = i;
      double maxA = abs( A[i][i] );
      for ( int k = i + 1; k < n; k++ )
      {
         double val = abs( A[k][i] );
         if ( val > maxA )
         {
            r = k;
            maxA = val;
         }
      }
      if ( r != i )
      {
         for ( int j = i; j < n; j++ ) swap( A[i][j], A[r][j] );
         det = -det;                                       // Swap rows - flip sign of determinant
      }

      // Row operations to make upper-triangular
      double pivot = A[i][i];
      if ( abs( pivot ) < SMALL ) return 0.0;              // Singular matrix

      for ( int r = i + 1; r < n; r++ )                    // Remove multiples from lower rows
      {
         double multiple = A[r][i] / pivot;                // Multiple of row i to clear element in ith column below
         for ( int j = i; j < n; j++ ) A[r][j] -= multiple * A[i][j];
      }
      det *= pivot;                                        // Determinant is product of diagonal elements
   }

   det *= A[n-1][n-1];

   return det;
}

//======================================================================

int main()
{
   matrix M = readMatrix( 21, "matrix.dat" );
   cout << "determinant = " << determinant( M ) << '\n';
}

//======================================================================

Output for sample matrix (below):
determinant = -0.0178605

Python Library Code (To check):
import numpy as np
M = np.loadtxt( "matrix.dat" )
print( np.linalg.det( M ) )

Output for sample matrix (below):
-0.017860521764216902

Sample 21x21 matrix (randomly generated with the generator below):
 0.72  0.11  0.79  0.51  0.51  0.85   0.4  0.75  0.44  0.03  0.95  0.03  0.65  0.21  0.95   0.2  0.16  0.86   0.2  0.17  0.75 
 0.38  0.74  0.73  0.06  0.07  0.56  0.83  0.11  0.78  0.66  0.19  0.32   0.7  0.28  0.73   0.3  0.06  0.12  0.04  0.25  0.47 
 0.34   0.8  0.53  0.28  0.61  0.54  0.35  0.65  0.81  0.19  0.86  0.09  0.14  0.96  0.39  0.84  0.92   0.7  0.95  0.84  0.37 
 0.06  0.36  0.44  0.35   0.9  0.47  0.57  0.22  0.79  0.48  0.59   0.2  0.18   0.1  0.84   0.4  0.78  0.05  0.67  0.19  0.92 
 0.53  0.88  0.49  0.95   0.1  0.73  0.27  0.93  0.36  0.36  0.73  0.81  0.71  0.95  0.67  0.61  0.07  0.48  0.76  0.79  0.68 
 0.31   0.1  0.04  0.42  0.65  0.23  0.72  0.11   0.3  0.43  0.32  0.37  0.45  0.52  0.73  0.53  0.54  0.78  0.24  0.48   0.6 
 0.54  0.71  0.86  0.69  0.09  0.91  0.28   0.5  0.81  0.38  0.38  0.31  0.16  0.63  0.64  0.15  0.08  0.07  0.64  0.76  0.81 
 0.14  0.13  0.54  0.96  0.31  0.02  0.23  0.49  0.44  0.83  0.82   0.6  0.26  0.55  0.96  0.33  0.55  0.05  0.03   0.8  0.53 
 0.69  0.15  0.02  0.26  0.73   0.1  0.25  0.44  0.04  0.39  0.49  0.51  0.29  0.85  0.64  0.56  0.85  0.25  0.31  0.05  0.75 
 0.28  0.43  0.18  0.52  0.54  0.63  0.38  0.47  0.08  0.54  0.03  0.01  0.52  0.19  0.34  0.71   0.9  0.11  0.34  0.68  0.41 
 0.47   0.3  0.18  0.76  0.35  0.61  0.89  0.86  0.02  0.66  0.38   0.2  0.86  0.12  0.09  0.69  0.79  0.64  0.36  0.03  0.87 
 0.64  0.06  0.92  0.37  0.34  0.13  0.95  0.38   0.9  0.51  0.48  0.31  0.12  0.19  0.94  0.28  0.82  0.62  0.83  0.24  0.96 
 0.92  0.17  0.83  0.64  0.52  0.51  0.08  0.64  0.38  0.21  0.99  0.02  0.45  0.37  0.78  0.79  0.24  0.98  0.14  0.75  0.13 
 0.46   0.4     0  0.84  0.74  0.32  0.78  0.84  0.41  0.82  0.34  0.39  0.71  0.92  0.17  0.07  0.23  0.39  0.11  0.93  0.98 
 0.45  0.38  0.45  0.69  0.55  0.33  0.46  0.69  0.82  0.82  0.07  0.98  0.03  0.03  0.78   0.5  0.71  0.01   0.6  0.66  0.44 
 0.29  0.25   0.7   0.1  0.08  0.53   0.6   0.4  0.84  0.56  0.67  0.87  0.19  0.58  0.54  0.95  0.63   0.3  0.45  0.59  0.91 
  0.8   0.2     0  0.37  0.76  0.21  0.41  0.92  0.25  0.16   0.7  0.72  0.41  0.01  0.36  0.64  0.39  0.52  0.03  0.04  0.55 
 0.58  0.19  0.47  0.33  0.38  0.16  0.78  0.72  0.63   0.3  0.41   0.4  0.76  0.99  0.93  0.98  0.83  0.06  0.83  0.39  0.94 
 0.31  0.92  0.56  0.82   0.4  0.34  0.04  0.02  0.04   0.3  0.34  0.37  0.42  0.18  0.45  0.19   0.2  0.97  0.81  0.89  0.44 
 0.29  0.27  0.46   0.2  0.36  0.08  0.36  0.97  0.97  0.94  0.55  0.61  0.93  0.16  0.32   0.6  0.62  0.48  0.66  0.39  0.99 
 0.82  0.98  0.24  0.81  0.34   0.4  0.65  0.09  0.76  0.93  0.32  0.38  0.38   0.9  0.34  0.69  0.19  0.08  0.55  0.15  0.75 

Simple matrix generator:
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   const int N = 21;
   srand( time( 0 ) );
   ofstream out( "matrix.dat" );
   for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
   {
      for ( int j = 0; j < N; j++ ) out << setw( 5 ) << 0.01 * ( rand() % 100) << " ";
      out << '\n';
   }
}


The programme you have given has worked properly. Thanks for your valuable discussion.
